# Using two screens and two desktops on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, display, virtual-desktop

My father wants to be a nerd and add another screen to his new Acer laptop. I think that is easy to do, but how could I make the original and extra-screen show different desktops. Aren't there some kind of programs for making virtual desktops? is there any other way? I've see pictures about this kind of "modifications".

I would appreciate it if someone would help me ;)

Martti Laine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest method is to make an image of the correct resolution and paste the two images you want in, but there's software such as Ultramon(not free, but fantastic stuff), or the free [DisplayFusion](http://www.binaryfortress.com/displayfusion/) software, which can do this for you automatically. Congratulate him on making the jump to multiple monitors, too - it's a night-and-day experience :)